# Calculo de contenidos de un array - PHP

Tags: php, array

He cargado un array a partir de elementos existentes en carpetas, 
Estos van desde el 20727 al 22772.
Dentro de ellos, busco si hay duplicados o diferencias.
Para ello, cuento la cantidad de elementos en el array, y hago un calculo simple:

```
$max = max($array);
$min = min($array);
$cantidad = count($array);
$diferencia = $max - $min - $cantidad;
// 22772 - 20727 - 2047 = -2;
```

Si hay diferencias positivas, me faltan elementos, y si hay negativas, hay duplicados.
En mi caso, al ser -2, hay duplicados, por lo que aplico esto para saber cuál es duplicado:

```
$ret = array_values(array_diff_assoc($array, array_unique($array)));
//Salida: var_dump() -> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "21018" }
```

Manualmente, voy a las carpetas, y me encuentro que, el número 21018, está repetido.
Perfecto, lo tomo y lo quito... pero aún así, estoy en -1.

¿En donde estoy fallando a los cálculos? 
¿Alguna de estas funciones está mal usada? 
¿Por que me "sobra" algo en el array?

Comment: Me perdí cuando empezaste a hablar de  `min` y de `max` y de *duplicados*. Quizá sea bueno que antes de dar explicaciones detalladas expliques en un breve párrafo qué es lo que quieres hacer de manera global y luego das los detalles.

Comment: No logro entenderlo. Empezaste a hablar de nombres de archivos en un array, y que en dicho array hay uno que sobra, por lo que restas 1 al total de elementos. A partir de ahi, todo lo que explicas es confuso. Lo del `min`  y el `max` es confuso, lo de los duplicados también. Lo primero es explicar el contexto brevemente para que quienes deban responder tengan una idea clara de la situación.

Comment: Lo he editado para que no haya confusion

Comment: el -2 quiere decir que son 2 archivos al eliminar uno de los dos no deberías tener negativo. seguro que ejecutaste la funcion correctamente?

Comment: Esa misma es mi duda, si me queda un -2, deberían ser 2 archivos, pero con la sgte funcion, solo encuentro uno... lo único que puedo pensar, es que algo en el array debe estar mal.

Comment: deberias de dejar un ejemplo del array...

Comment: Visualmente estoy revisandolo... donde te puedo copiar el array de 2047 elementos ?

Comment: con un ejemplo de 5 elementos es suficiente... pero ya se por donde viene el error...

Comment: cuando analizas un array te lo compara vs el primero... si la diferencia es al revés no te la devuelve tienes que iterar todo varias veces...

Comment: Tu fórmula está mal. Deseas comprobar si en la secuencia de números hay duplicados o por el contrario hay saltos. Restar el menor elemento de la secuencia menos el mayor elemento te devuelve la cantidad de elementos - 1. Es decir si tienes `n` elementos en la secuencia, al realizar la resta de mayor menos el menor, el resultado será siempre `n-1`. Luego a ese valor le estás restando `n`, por lo cual siempre tendrás como resultado final `-1`. Debes restar `n - 1`, para que se anulen (si es lo que quieres). Aunque podrías trabajar con `-1` como discriminante. Ya eso es a gusto tuyo. Saludos